# Django foreignkey mismatch error not allowing classes to have relation in database

Tags: django, mismatch

I am trying to add a foreign key to the posts class so that each person can have multiple posts, I keep getting a foreign key mismatch error.  The tables are empty.  I don't understand what the problem here is.

```
"""
Definition of models.
"""

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Users(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=30)

class Posts(models.Model):
     priority = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     client = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
     assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     exp_comp_time = models.FloatField(max_length=4)
     percent_comp = models.FloatField(max_length=4)
     post_date = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     due_date = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     latest_mod = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)


>>> newPost = Posts(priority="low", client="maserati", title="models", 
assigned_to=newUser.name, exp_comp_time=5.5, percent_comp=75.2, 
post_date="6/25/19", due_date="7/1/19")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File 
repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\office_proj_en 
v\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 483, in __init__
_setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
File 
repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\office_proj_en 
v\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 
211, 
in __set__
self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "'Dave'": "Posts.assigned_to" must be a "Users" 
instance.


>>> newPost = Posts(priority="low", client="maserati", title="models", 
assigned_to="Dave", exp_comp_time=5.5, percent_comp=75.2, 
post_date="6/25/19", due_date="7/1/19")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File 
repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\office_proj_en 
v\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 483, in __init__
_setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
File 
repos\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\office_proj_en 
v\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 
211, in __set__
self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "'Dave'": "Posts.assigned_to" must be a "Users" 
instance.
```

When I go to migrate I get this error:
django.db.utils.operationalError: foreign key mismatch - "app_posts" referencing "app_users"

Comment: Why have you made `name` the primary key in Users?

Comment: Idk what full traceback mean.  I only named  name as primary key because if I take it off I get and error saying: you are trying to add anon-nullable field 'id' to users without a default: we can't do that (the database needs soemthing to populate existing rows)  but I already fluesh my database

Comment: Delete your database and remove the migrations, then start again.

Comment: Daniel that worked great, thank you.  But now when I go to populate my tables in the python shell, I first enter a user "John", then when I go to enter a post whether it I use a variable for the Users.name or just "John" for the assigned to field I get an error that says posts.assigned_to must be a Users instance.

Comment: Please show the full code you used and the traceback (as an edit to the question).

Comment: Assuming `newUser` is an instance of Users, you should assign that directly rather than using its name: `newPost = Posts(..., assigned_to=newUser, ...)`.

Comment: I figured it out, I just needed to use newUser instead of newUser.name or "Dave".  Thanks a lot for you help Daniel.